# Find the nearest neighbour with more than 3 dimension

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn, nearest-neighbor, recommendation-engine

I have a database with 2000 data and 15 features(columns) and I want to make a recommendation system to recommend me most similar row with the row that I've chosen.

For example, I want to find the most similar row with row 150 in my database.

which algorithm do you recommend to help me with this project?

Does KNN practical for this question?

---

This is one row of my data :

```
name1 = 12\241\42\0.4\0.5 ... \241
```

As you see all of my datasets are numeric except name column.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [reprex] with expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like KNN is what you are looking for. To implement a multi-dimensional KNN, I would suggest you look at the Euclidean distance equation:

[Euclidean distance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DUMw.png)

This determines the distance of one 'row' to another. You can then calculate which 'k' rows are closest using this equation.

Comment: KNN will put your data in the number of clusters you specify, but not tell you the closest point. Why not just calculate pairwise distance matrix from `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist()` ?

Comment: I agree with Sergey. This is sensible.